# CRT not yielding smallest possible x?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have the following congruencies:
$$x= 4(mod 7) $$
$$x= 2(mod 4) $$
$$x= 2(mod 5) $$

I solved for the smallest possible x that satisfies all of those conditions by breaking it up like so:
$$a= 4(mod 7) $$
$$a= 0(mod 4) $$
$$a= 0(mod 5) $$ which gets a = 60

$$b= 0(mod 7) $$
$$b= 2(mod 4) $$
$$b= 0(mod 5) $$ which gets b = 70

$$c= 0(mod 7) $$
$$c= 0(mod 4) $$
$$c= 2(mod 5) $$ which gets c = 112

then I do $$ a + b + c = 242 $$

But it says the answer is 102.

I tried it like this too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIFehsBHB8o
and got the same answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. The answer is indeed $a+b+c = 242\pmod {7\times4\times5}$.

Comment: The answer is not "$242$", it is rather "$x\equiv242\pmod{140}$".

Comment: ooh gotcha! thank you

Comment: I think OP wants a method  using hand. What I see in solution advised  in the link is a computer program not a solution. I will give my solution if the question is reopened.